# How to Roll up recursive value in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I have a table with value for example

```
ID    Name    ParentID   Value   Date
1     ClassA   0          NULL    NULL
2     ClassB   0          NULL    NULL
7     Jason    1           50     2016-06-01
8     Jason    1           20     2016-06-02
9     Jason    1           30     2016-06-03
10    Kelly    1           20     2016-06-02
11    Kelly    1           30     2016-06-03
```

and i want to generate a report like this

```
               2016-06-01   2016-06-02   2016-06-03
ClassA            50             40           60
   Jason          50             20           30
   Kelly          0              20           30
ClassB            0               0            0
```

as you can see, the classA has been rolled up and total up all the children

i tried few code, it either show me empty or show me recursive value where all the rows is the same value.

for example
=Sum(fields!QTY.Value)
it shows 
[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPE37.png)

Then second code i  tried is

=IIF(ISNOTHING(Sum(Fields!QTY.Value, "Name", recursive)),0,  Sum(Fields!QTY.Value, "Name", recursive))
, it shows 
[Recursive result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNs7G.png)

Anyone can help on this?..

Comment: Can you post you query or your Result of dataset you get  ?

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this?  I have the same issue

Comment: I did not found any resolution for this.. my resolution is to populate the total amount at my query which is in my sql then retrieve.. it seems faster that way